# Redshift: Incremental products ordered across marketplaces

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table, 'Customer_Orders' that basically lists the products purchased by customers across marketplaces (UK, DE, US etc). Here's a short overview of the table:

| Cust_id | marketplace | product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | UK | A |
| 1 | UK | B |
| 1 | DE | A |
| 1 | US | A |
| 1 | US | C |

From the above table, i want to extract, the incremental number of products ordered 1. in total; 2. by marketplace. For eg: If we use UK as the base, Total: 3; DE: 0 and US: 1.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the differences like this?

```
select cust_id, marketplace,
       (count(*) - max(case when marketplace = 'UK' then count(*) end) over (partition by cust_id)) as diff_from_uk
from Customer_Orders co
group by cust_id, marketplace;
```